# Bring up virtual input plugin from QML

Tags: qt, qml

Searching for an alternative to Qt's official VirtualKeyboard I came across this [MockupVirtualKeyboard](https://github.com/tolszak/MockupVirtualKeyboard) repository. It is based on QPlatformInputContext. I build and installed the plugin to Qt5.15.2/plugins/platforminputcontexts, but I dont know how to bring the Virtual Keyboard up.

What I would like to achieve, using QML, is:

```
TextInput{
  text: ""
  onFocusChanged: showVirtualInput()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the keyboard then you must set the environment variable "QT_IM_MODULE" to be "mockup", and you can do that by placing the following line of code in the main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("mockup"));

#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    # ...
```

On the other hand, you must change:

```
Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface" FILE "mockup.json")
```

to

```
Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.qt-project.Qt.QPlatformInputContextFactoryInterface.5.1" FILE "mockup.json")
```

in the mockupplatforminputcontextplugin.h file, recompile and install the file so that it is compatible with Qt 5.15.2